# How to allow traffic through vlan

Tags: vlan

I have router connected directly to Antenna from G0/4 and when connected PC to G0/1 the internet working normally as Fig. 1 in below Photo.
I need to change the router place so i create vlan 500 in Coreswitch and connect the antenna to switch with Fa 0/6 "Switch port mode access" & assign it to "Vlan500".
also assign port Fa0/10 in "User SW" to router with "Switch port mode access" & assign it to "Vlan500".
but the internet not working.

[image: Network]

Maybe i have missed some something.

your help will be highly appreciated

Thanks 
also

Comment: Did you create the vlan on each switch with the command "vlan 500"?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the network device models and configurations. We can only guess where you may have gone wrong, and speculation is off-topic here.

Comment: Yes, i create the vlan 500 in the coreswitch and already deployed in the other switches.

Comment: Coreswitch model: 6509 , edge switches: cisco 2960

Comment: Moudmn, we can't help you unless you give us more information.  Please edit your question to include the configurations of your switches.